# Line separators between elements in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a line of elements using `display:flex;` in CSS with the same spacing for text.

Here is what i got, i achived it using `display: inline-block;` and spacing differences between text - which i would want to make the same for every text.

```css
element {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  color: rgb(0, 146, 247);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.footertext {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(124, 134, 205);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="footertext">
    First Line
  </p>
  <element></element>
  <p class="footertext">
    ABC
  </p>
  <element></element>
  <p class="footertext">
    Third Line
  </p>
  <element></element>
  <p class="footertext">
    DEFG
  </p>
</div>
```

I need those funny elements between text and when i try to use `display:flex;` those are going out of bounds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simplified way of doing it.

```css
.footer-texts {
  display: flex;
  color:rgb(124,134,205);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.footer-texts > span {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}
.footer-texts > span:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  top: 25%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:rgb(0, 146,247);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-texts">
  <span>First Line</span>
  <span>ABC</span>
  <span>Third Line<br />two lines</span>
  <span>DEFG</span>
</div>
```

A few notes:

- rather than adding the same class to all children, just add one to the parent and style using `.someClassName > span` (where `someClassName` is the class name and `span` is the child selector.
- whenever possible, use pseudo-elements instead of DOM elements to add separators or any other type of decorators to your markup. In this particular case `border-right` would have been a good candidate, too.

Comment: Thank you for input, my question is kind of confusing but i really need similar width and height of elements like in my example but using flexbox and with same spacing between words.

Comment: You want them to have equal width?

Comment: It would be amazing

Comment: Updated. Now they will have equal width and stretch to occupy the full width of the parent. They'll also have equal height to the tallest of them and always center the content of the children vertically.

Comment: Those border lines are quite long and i have no idea how to make them shorter,

Comment: You can either reduce the padding on the spans or reduce the height of the pseudo's. I chose the latter.

Comment: Fixed :) ... missed the small left alignment when text wrapped ... and the `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, which I guess you found out :)

Answer (score 17):

How about flex, with a left border on all elements except the first:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

.footertext {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.footertext + .footertext {
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(0, 146, 247);
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.footertext {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(124, 134, 205);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="footertext">First Line</p>
  <p class="footertext">ABC</p>
  <p class="footertext">Third Line</p>
  <p class="footertext">DEFG</p>
</div>
```